# Need an order preserve nested list duplicate remover

Tags: python, list

I've got a nested list like

```
L = [[0,1,2,5,6],[1,2,9,4],[3,8,5,5,5]]
```

And i want to remove all duplicates like this:

```
L2 = [[0,1,2,5,6],[9,4],[3,8]]
```

All function I found, flat list or doesn't remove duplicate in child list.

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using set and a list-comprehension:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> seen_add = seen.add
>>> [[x for x in lst if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)] for lst in L]  
[[0, 1, 2, 5, 6], [9, 4], [3, 8]]
```

The above code can also be written as:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> out = []
>>> for lst in L:
    temp = []
    for x in lst:
        if x not in seen:
            temp.append(x)
            seen.add(x)
    out.append(temp)
...     
>>> out
[[0, 1, 2, 5, 6], [9, 4], [3, 8]]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of ```seen_add = seen.add``` in the list comprehension example?

Comment: @wnnmaw A micro-optimization to prevent unnecessary attribute look up.

Comment: seen_add = seen.add - is this necessary? Why not seen.add(x)?

Comment: @helloV Not necessary, see my previous comment.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  I will start using that technique (micro optimization) from now on. Thanks.

Comment: @helloV If you look into CPython source code, you can find many instances of such attribute caching, for example: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f7fd2776e80d/Lib/heapq.py#l372.
Other implementations like PyPy and Pyston have their own way to speedup such attribute lookups. (http://morepypy.blogspot.in/2011/03/controlling-tracing-of-interpreter-with_21.html  and https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2014/04/introducing-pyston-an-upcoming-jit-based-python-implementation/)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @PauloScardine I was waiting for this comment. ;-)

Comment: of course, Mr. Chaudhary, you have 100k+ reputation. Sorry to disrespect you sir, it was meant to @helloV. :-)